# Max-width suddenly stopped working in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have own and develop a website www.frittfallfoto.no, to display my photo archive. Last Sunday Google Chrome suddenly changed the way it displays my menu system. I did not change any code, or encounter any errors. It seems the browser disregards the CSS max-width property, and lists my meny items in a long line extending out of the screen boundaries. Microsoft Edge browser displays the correct result. See images for understanding the problem:

Chrome image: https://www.frittfallfoto.no/Chrome-browser.jpg

Edge image: https://www.frittfallfoto.no/Edge-browser.jpg

What's even stranger, the Chrome browser at my work computer displayed the correct result yesterday (Monday), and I verified the browser versions at home and work were identical (76.0.3809.132, 64-bit). Today, however, the problem was the same at the work computer.

Tried the code in W3schools try-it-editor, and it works there.

CSS:

```
#container {
max-width: 1140px;
width: 100%;
display: table;
text-align: justify;
}

.button {
  background-color: #ff7c3f; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
 }
```

PHP code, simplified:

```
<?php
   echo "<div id='container'>";
   while($counter<$number_of_items)
   {
      echo "<a href='wp_arkiv.php?query'><button class='button'>DESCRIPTION</button></a>&nbsp;";
   }
   echo "</div>";
?>
```

HTML, actual code:

```
<div id='container'>
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=1&=Geografisk'><button class='button'>Geografisk</button></a>&nbsp;<a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=7&administrativt=Norge'><button class='button'>Norge</button></a><br><br>
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=131&administrativt=Akershus'><button class='button'>Akershus</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=132&administrativt=Aust-Agder'><button class='button'>Aust-Agder</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=133&administrativt=Buskerud'><button class='button'>Buskerud</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=134&administrativt=Finnmark'><button class='button'>Finnmark</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=135&administrativt=Hedmark'><button class='button'>Hedmark</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=136&administrativt=Hordaland'><button class='button'>Hordaland</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=137&administrativt=Møre og Romsdal'><button class='button'>Møre og Romsdal</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=138&administrativt=Nordland'><button class='button'>Nordland</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=139&administrativt=Oppland'><button class='button'>Oppland</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=140&administrativt=Oslo'><button class='button'>Oslo</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=141&administrativt=Rogaland'><button class='button'>Rogaland</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=142&administrativt=Sogn og Fjordane'><button class='button'>Sogn og Fjordane</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=143&administrativt=Telemark'><button class='button'>Telemark</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=144&administrativt=Troms'><button class='button'>Troms</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=145&administrativt=Trøndelag'><button class='button'>Trøndelag</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=146&administrativt=Vest-Agder'><button class='button'>Vest-Agder</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=147&administrativt=Vestfold'><button class='button'>Vestfold</button></a>&nbsp;
   <a href='wp_arkiv.php?punktID=148&administrativt=Østfold'><button class='button'>Østfold</button></a>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML structure as well.

Comment: Hi, we need to see the HTML, not the PHP that creates the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I have displayed the actual code created.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution may be to change the container to display: flex;

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Do some research on flexbox. You'll find it excellent at tackling many issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out. However, it seems Chrome interprets the width or max-width properties differently since last Sunday, causing the problem. The original code has been working perfectly for more than a year, and suddenly it stops without me changing anything. Link to the actual website page: https://www.frittfallfoto.no/wp_arkiv.php?punktID=7&administrativt=Norge.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is now solved. Turns out it was a buck in Chrome 77. With version 78 it all works like a charm again. Thanks.